# Rails, destroy link NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following list of items:

```
= @kid.educations.each do |education|
            = education.studies_centre
            = _('-')
            = education.city_and_country
            = link_to _("<i class='fa fa-times-circle a-lg'></i> delete").html_safe, education, :confirm => 'Are you sure?',:method => :delete, class: "btn btn-danger btn-xs pull-right"
            %br
            %small
              = education.academic_qualification
            %hr
            %br
```

As you can see, I have a delete option, but I does not work. I get:

```
undefined method `education_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fd00c61c270>:0x007fd00cdd5b88>
```

What I'm doing wrong.

Thanks for your help

UPDATE ROUTES

---

```
                dashboard_kid_educations GET      /dashboard/kids/:kid_id/educations(.:format)                           dashboard/educations#index
                                              POST     /dashboard/kids/:kid_id/educations(.:format)                           dashboard/educations#create
                  new_dashboard_kid_education GET      /dashboard/kids/:kid_id/educations/new(.:format)                       dashboard/educations#new
                 edit_dashboard_kid_education GET      /dashboard/kids/:kid_id/educations/:id/edit(.:format)                  dashboard/educations#edit
                      dashboard_kid_education GET      /dashboard/kids/:kid_id/educations/:id(.:format)                       dashboard/educations#show
                                              PUT      /dashboard/kids/:kid_id/educations/:id(.:format)                       dashboard/educations#update
                                              DELETE   /dashboard/kids/:kid_id/educations/:id(.:format)                       dashboard/educations#destroy
```

Comment: Show your `routes.rb` or output of `rake routes`.

Comment: Routes ready on the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using namespaced nested resources, so your link should be like this:

```
 = link_to _("<i class='fa fa-times-circle a-lg'></i> delete").html_safe, [:dashboard, @kid, education], :confirm => 'Are you sure?',:method => :delete, class: "btn btn-danger btn-xs pull-right"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, It works, the only problem if that it show me the "Are you sure? alert 3 times.

Answer (score 1):

If you using nested resources you should pass 2 arguments to path helper. And I think it's better to use block to improve code readability

```
= link_to dashboard_kid_education_path(@kid, education), confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-danger btn-xs pull-right' do
  %i.fa.fa-times-circle.a-lg
  = 'delete'
```

Answer (score 0):

**Nested Routes**

Something to add to `Marek`'s answer is the idea of [`nested routes`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)

Essentially, when you define a *nested* route (like below), Rails does not instinctively know when you're calling this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :dashboard do
    resources :education
end
```

The bottom line is that Rails will only call routes as they pertain to the `model` of the object you're calling. In your example, you call `education` (which is presumably built from `Eduction.find()`)

To Rails, by passing this to your `routes`, you will essentially tell your application to find routes for the `Education` model only, hence why your error looks like this:

```
undefined method `education_path'
```

--

The way to fix this, as detailed by `Marek` is to ensure you are referencing the correct path in your `<%= link_to %>` call. To do this, you have to reference the *nested* route as described by Marek's solution